# segmentation fault for inet_ntoa

Tags: c

```
    #include <stdio.h> 
    #include <string.h> /* for strncpy */ 
    #include <sys/types.h> 
    #include <sys/socket.h> 
    #include <sys/ioctl.h> 
    #include <netinet/in.h> 
    #include <net/if.h> 

    int 
    main() 
    { 
     int fd;  
     struct ifreq ifr; 

     fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);  

     /* I want to get an IPv4 IP address */ 
     ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET; 

     /* I want IP address attached to "eth0" */ 
     strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, "eth0", IFNAMSIZ-1); 

     ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr); 

     close(fd); 

     /* display result */ 
     char* ipaddr; 
     ipaddr = inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&(ifr.ifr_addr))->sin_addr); 
     printf("%s\n", ipaddr); 

     return 0; 
    }
```

for this line:

```
     ipaddr = inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&(ifr.ifr_addr))->sin_addr);
```

I get

```
iptry.c: In function ‘main’:
iptry.c:31:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

and for

```
     printf("%s\n", ipaddr);
```

I get segmentation fault.

What is wrong with this?

Comment: in linux, `inet_ntoa` is defined in the header `<arpa/inet.h>`, perhaps you need to `#include` that?

Comment: Do you get an _implicit function declaration_ warning also?

Comment: what do you mean by implicit function declaration?

Comment: ah, <arpa/inet.h> is very important!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`inet_ntoa` is defined in the header `<arpa/inet.h>`,
need to `#include`, otherwise, there will be errors

Comment: How is that the compiler didn't throw a warning if he didn't included the right header ??

Answer (score 2):

`inet_ntoa` does not demand a pointer, but value

```
 char* ipaddr; 
 ipaddr = inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in)(ifr.ifr_addr))->sin_addr);
```

If `sin_addr` is a pointer, you'll need to dereference it.

`inet_ntoa` will return `NULL` if there is an error, so trying to `printf` a NULL will cuase a segmentation fault...

Look [here](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/inet_ntoaman.html) for information and [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_ntoa) for the man-page.

Comment: Like I stated in my answer and if you get errors, read the documentation, ALWAYS!

Comment: Nowhere in either of your references does it say anything about returning NULL on an error. And what kind of error can there be in a 32-bit value?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to see the warning, just cast the return value of inet_ntoa

```
ipaddr = (char *) inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&(ifr.ifr_addr))->sin_addr);
```

The segmentation fault is probably because some of the previous function returns an error (null value) and you didn't check it

The same code worked in my Linux Box.

Comment: still can't figure out the problem

Comment: fd is a valid file descriptor? ioctl returned -1 or whatever? ifr contains valid values? inet_ntoa returned a null pointer? answer the questions and then you'll get what's the problem

Comment: fd is valid, iotcl return 0, inet_ntoa returns valid value, how to check ifr?

Comment: inet_ntoa returns a non-null value? are you sure?