# segmentation fault in linux (socket programming (TCP) in C)

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, segmentation-fault

I am just learning socket programming on Linux by some websites and here are some parts of my code on server side by using TCP:

```
#define BufferLength 100
#define SERVPORT 3111
int main()
{
  /* Variable and structure definitions. */
  int sd, sd2, rc, length = sizeof(int);
  int totalcnt = 0, on = 1;
  char temp;
  char buffer[BufferLength];
  struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
  struct sockaddr_in their_addr;
  fd_set read_fd;

  /* Get a socket descriptor */
  if((sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
  {
    perror("Server-socket() error");
    exit (-1);
  }
  else
    printf("Server-socket() is OK\n");

  /* Allow socket descriptor to be reusable */
  if((rc = setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&on, sizeof(on))) < 0)
  {
    perror("Server-setsockopt() error");
    close(sd);
    exit (-1);
  }
  else
    printf("Server-setsockopt() is OK\n");

  /* bind to an address */
  memset(&serveraddr, 0x00, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
  serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serveraddr.sin_port = htons(SERVPORT);
  serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  printf("Using %s, listening at %d\n", inet_ntoa(serveraddr.sin_addr), SERVPORT);

  /* continue */
}
```

When I did the last line (printf("using......")), I got a segmentation fault, why? Thanks.

Comment: Your code looks good, and it works for me.  Running it under valgrind does not reveal any memory-related issues that would explain a segfault.  I did add all the requisite headers; I guess there's a chance that your problem arises from you missing one or more of those.  Does your compiler emit any warnings?

Comment: Hi John, there is no warning when I compile this program. Also, when I run similar code with this, I don't have any segmentation error.

Comment: @user, I've tried to compile your piece of code on my Linux and it's runs without any segmentation fault. Are you sure the segmentation fault occurs at the printf? What's the code after the printf?

Comment: @user, the code you presented is fine.  Supposing that you included all the needed headers in the full translation unit from which you built the program -- and your compiler should have complained if you did not -- I am inclined to believe that the given code does not correspond to the program that segfaulted on you.

Comment: similar code, e.g. UDP server side code

Comment: Hmm.  I agree with @John, nothing jumps out at me.  Recommend using a local variable on the inet_ntoa result and inspecting is (via debugger) before the print...maybe you are somehow getting a bad pointer return?

Comment: Sergio, John: I am sure that the problem is on inet_ntoa(serveraddr.sin_addr), since if I only print SERVPORT, there is no problem.

Comment: Code runs as-is on Centos 6 and Centos 7.

Comment: Also, since others are having no issues, please note your compiler, environment, and build target platform.

Comment: You would be well advised to follow @Speed8ump's advice to sort this out via a debugger.  Accepting the return value of `inet_ntoa()` in a local variable, as he suggests, will make that a bit more convenient.

Comment: Try to use code such as `char * ascaddr; ascaddr=inet_ntoa(); if (ascaddr==NULL) {puts("Error"); exit(-2);}` just for debugging purpose!

Comment: @Sergio, I have tried char * ascaddr; ascaddr=inet_ntoa(serveraddr.sin_addr); printf("Server-Using %s..\n", serveraddr.sin_addr); and it prints Server-Using (null)..

Comment: @user, `serveraddr.sin_addr` is not a char pointer, it contains 0 then printf returns null! You've to verify what's the behaviour of inet_ntoa!

Comment: You've to try to use `printf("Server-Using %s..\n", ascaddr);`! If also with `ascaddr` you've the same problem try `printf("Server-Using %p..\n", ascaddr);` the hex number you will see will be the pointer `inet_ntoa()` returns, if you report it maybe you or we can understand the problem!

Comment: Does your "real" code `#include` the header to provide `inet_ntoa()`'s prototype and you are on 64bits? Does the code compile without warnings?

Comment: There is no need to call a library function to turn `0.0.0.0` into a string. It's already a constant. In any case your code is lying to you. The `printf()` that is failing says 'listening' when you haven't actually done either of the two things required to make it listen. You need a `bind()` and a `listen()` call for that claim to be true.

Comment: @Sergio, I am sorry that I made a mistake, I should print ascaddr rather than serveraddr.sin_addr. By the way, my problem is solved, many thanks for all of you.

Comment: @user. I'm curios about the issue you had! What was the cause of the segmentation fault?

Comment: @Sergio, I think that the problem is what alk mentioned in the anwser.

Comment: Ok! ... We've to keep in mind: always include all necessary includes!!! (y) :)

Comment: @SergioFormiggini: It's more about enabling the compiler to warn and taking such warnings serious ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code as shown misses to `#include` any headers, so as it stands won't compile due to some undefined symbols.

It would compile however if you missed to just prototype any library functions referenced by the code, which would lead to any function being assumed to return `int`.

The latter fact might be fatal or not.

On a 64bit system at least it is fatal in the case of `inet_ntoa()` used as a parameter to `printf()`, as on a 64bit system it most likely is expected to return a 64bit (`char`-pointer) value (but a 32bit `int`). So (assuming the prototype misses) when generating the code the compilers assumes `inet_ntoa()` to return a 32bit `int` which would lead to "chopping-off" the most significant 32bits of the address returned. Trying to `printf()` from such a "crippled" and therefore (most likely) invalid address provokes undefined behaviour and in your case leads to the segmentation violation observed.

To fix this, add the relevant prototype (for `inet_ntoa()`) by adding:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

The compiler should have warned you about this. To enable all compiler's warnings for gcc use the options `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.  Take such warnings serious.

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that inet_ntoa() is somehow returning NULL, leading to the segfault when it is dereferenced in the printf().  I can't find a direct reference plainly stating that this is possible with the Linux version of inet_ntoa, but I found several people who made that claim, and it is the only point in that code where a pointer is being dereferenced.

The answer at the bottom of this question: [segmentation fault for inet_ntoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15635803/segmentation-fault-for-inet-ntoa) makes the claim that inet_ntoa can return NULL.  However, following his reference links, I couldn't find an actual statement of that fact.

There is an MSDN article (which is suggestive, but of course doesn't apply directly to Linux code) that does state plainly that inet_ntoa() can return NULL here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738564%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Hard to believe it returns NULL for INADDR_ANY. Hard to believe there is such a thing as a possible error in a 32-bit argument value in the first place.

Comment: Kind of agree with you on the first point, but there aren't many other candidates there for a segfault, which leads me to this as the only possible candidate, even if unlikely.  As far as error from a 32-bit argument, aren't there a fairly large number of values that would not translate into valid 32-bit IP addresses?